# Basic questions on producing a Beamer handout

Tags: beamer, pgfpages

I use beamer for my lectures and post the handout on the course website.  I create the handout with pgfpages.  Here MWE:

```
\documentclass[handout,compress,mathserif]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}[border shrink=1mm,frame=true]
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{3}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{4}{border code=\pgfusepath{stroke}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

What I would like to do is make it easy for the students to read the slides, and I have some issues.

1. I cannot figure out how to number the frames properly!  I often use plain frames and I cannot figure out how to number these.  So there are no page numbers on my slides, and therefore they are missing from the handout too.
2. The frame has a border, which is visible on the PDF reader of TexShop and on (Mac) Preview, but on Adobe Reader it only shows when the file is zoomed out enough.  Any idea of what's happening?

If you have any recommendations for producing handouts, they are most welcome.  I looked online extensively, and settle for what's shown in the example.

Comment: I have to admit that this is something of an issue for me with beamer. I've even had colleagues (who do not, of course, use anything as anachronistic as LaTeX) express their surprise that my software cannot easily perform such a simple function (unlike that better known slide-producing software). I like the idea of doing it in one document, too. The closest I've come involves having a second document include the slides using pdfpages. Then I can get headers, footers etc. and could probably number slides, too, but it is a pain.

Comment: Page numbers can be added by modifying the `footlines` template, as long as you don't use the `[plain]` option for the frames. Is this an option for you?

Answer (score 3):

> 1. I cannot figure out how to number the frames properly! I often use plain frames and I cannot figure out how to number these. So there are no page numbers on my slides, and therefore they are missing from the handout too.

A few suggestions about numbering plain frames: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/349510/36296

> 2. The frame has a border, which is visible on the PDF reader of TexShop and on (Mac) Preview, but on Adobe Reader it only shows when the file is zoomed out enough. Any idea of what's happening?

That is just an artefact of the pdf viewer which does not display lines if they are too small. If you make the lines thicker, they are also visible with `Adobe Reader`

```
\documentclass[handout,compress]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}[border shrink=1mm]
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}{border code=\pgfsetlinewidth{3pt}\pgfusepath{stroke}}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}{border code=\pgfsetlinewidth{3pt}\pgfusepath{stroke}}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{3}{border code=\pgfsetlinewidth{3pt}\pgfusepath{stroke}}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{4}{border code=\pgfsetlinewidth{3pt}\pgfusepath{stroke}}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\hfill\insertframenumber}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}
a
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{}
a
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{}
a
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{}
a
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]