# How to show the page number in plain frame?

Tags: beamer, header-footer

In beamer I have a frame that is `plain`. (I use plain frame to remove the table of contents in header and the footer icons.)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]
  \frametitle{Agenda}
  Here we go...
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

When I use `plain`, the page numbering in the footer disappear. How can I show them without removing `plain`?

Comment: Could you provide the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates the current result? Also, where do you want to place the page number if there is no footer?

Comment: The easiest solution would be to use the tikzpagenodes package and manually add \tikz[remember picture,overlay]{\node at (current page footer area) {\thepage};}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some possibilities:

1. Just remove the headline and leave the footline in place.
2. A layer, which is always present, even on plain frames, are the navigation symbols. If you don't use them, simply replace them by the frame number. But in case you want to keep them, it's also possible to add the framenumber to the existing symbols.

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\begin{document}

%Possibility 1
{
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\vskip-\headheight}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Agenda}
  Here we go...
\end{frame}
}

%Possibility 2
{
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{\insertframenumber}
\begin{frame}[plain]
  \frametitle{Agenda}
  Here we go...
\end{frame}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! Just a bug: in Possibility 1, there should be no `[plain]` because that will remove the footer too!

Comment: I'm quite surprised that there's no way to set a global flag such that all slides have a frame counter, regardless of whether or not they are plain? :/

Comment: At least for the template I'm testing this with (derived from Pittsburgh), Option (1) fails to move the slide contents up. You need to add a second `\vskip-\headheight` after the `{frame}`. Option (2) also isn't suitable: it won't always render in the same style as the normal frame numbers, and you need to add some additional code to make sure the template's own frame-counter code is removed (if present).

Comment: @MRule Given that the Pittsburg theme does not have a headline, option 1 works as expected. Option 2: If you want to keep the same style, insert the `page number in head/foot` template. You don't need to remove the templates own frame counter, because the frame uses the plain option and thus does not show the footline.

Comment: I said *derived from* Pittsburgh, not Pittsburgh; Evidently this particular template has been modified. I'd presumed this issue could crop up with other templates users may encounter. This is why I opened with the qualification "At least for the template I'm testing this with" rather than making a stronger claim like "for the Pittsburgh template" or "For many templates". Is the implication that this specific issue is a bug almost surely unique to my template, and won't be encountered by others?

Comment: @MRule Well, if you don't show your particular template, what's the point in commenting?

Comment: I was having the same problem as MRule and non of the solutions was working. However I found (don't ask why) the following environment does work:`\makeatletter  \newenvironment{withoutheadline}{\setbeamertemplate{headline}[default] \def\beamer@entrycode{\vspace*{-\headheight}}}{}\makeatother`. Then surround whole frame with `\begin{withoutheadline} ... \end{withoutheadline}`